# Prisma automatically create related row when parent is created

Tags: mysql, prisma

I have a schema looking like this

```
model User {
  id       Int      @default(autoincrement())
  settings Settings
}

model Settings {
  userId     Int
  settingOne Boolean @default(false)
  user       User    @relation(fields: [userId], references: [id], onDelete: Cascade)
}
```

I don't want settings in user to be optional - is there a way I can automatically have a corresponding row created in the settings table whenever a user is created?

Comment: As @Danila mentioned `settings` need to be optional because both sides of the relation cannot be required. To solve the problem of automatically creating `Settings` alongside a `User`, perhaps you could use the `connectOrCreate` operator to create the appropriate `Settings` alongside a `User` record? Another possible solution would be to write a [Prisma middleware](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-client/middleware) that creates a `Settings` record after the `User` record is created and connects it to the `User` record.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible because if both sides of relation are required then how would you create any of them? So the side of the relation without a relation scalar (the field representing the foreign key in the database) must be optional. You can decide yourself which one though.

For example, you want to create `User` but `Settings` is required, so you need to create `Settings` first. But to create `Settings` you need the `User` too, because it is required on the `Settings` model.

[More info in the docs](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-schema/relations/one-to-one-relations#required-and-optional-1-1-relation-fields)

Answer (score 2):

I am doing something very similar in mine:

```js
const publication = await prisma.publication.create({
    data: {
        title: e.title,
        type: e.type,
        content: e.content,
        user: {
            connect: {
                id: user.id
            }
        },
        publicationStatus: {
            create: {
                status: 'DRAFT'
            }
        }
    }
});
```

All of our `publications` have a correspending `publicationStatus`, similar to the problem you list, perhaps you could do:

```js
await prisma.user.create({
    data: {
        settings: {
            create: {
                settingOne: true
            }
        }
    }
})
```

or something similar?

Answer (score 0):

if you're using SQL what you can do is create a procedure that will run on user insert